# `dplyr::arrange()` is not accurate with foreign language text: is it operator-error or the function? `sort()` does it correctly

Tags: r, dplyr

When using `dplyr::arrange()` with Greek text, it does not order the data correctly. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)

wds <- structure(list(
  Word = c("θέση", "ταχυδρομείο", "γραμματόσημο", "προσπάθεια", "τηλεφωνώ", 
           "επικοινωνώ", "υπογραφή", "γλώσσα", "έξοδος", "μήνυμα", 
           "πραγματικότητα", "μυστικό", "διαδίκτυο", "δίκτυο"), 
  trans2 = c("the seat, position, job, post, station, status", 
             "the post office, postal service", "the postage stamp", 
             "the attempt (to do something), try (to accomplish something)",
             "to phone, to telephone (the act of calling someone)", 
             "to talk, interact, contact, communicate", "the signature, (fig) agreement",
             "the (anatomy, shoe, figuratively) tongue, language, (fish species) sole", 
             "the exit, outing, the act of going out, exodus",
             "the (lit or fig) message, email, text, SMS", 
             "the reality, actuality", "the secret, mystery", "the internet", 
             "the computer network")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")

wds %>% arrange(Word)
#              Word                                                                  trans2
# 1          έξοδος                          the exit, outing, the act of going out, exodus
# 2          γλώσσα the (anatomy, shoe, figuratively) tongue, language, (fish species) sole
# 3    γραμματόσημο                                                       the postage stamp
# 4          δίκτυο                                                    the computer network
# 5       διαδίκτυο                                                            the internet
# 6      επικοινωνώ                                 to talk, interact, contact, communicate
# 7            θέση                          the seat, position, job, post, station, status
# 8          μήνυμα                              the (lit or fig) message, email, text, SMS
# 9         μυστικό                                                     the secret, mystery
# 10 πραγματικότητα                                                  the reality, actuality
# 11     προσπάθεια            the attempt (to do something), try (to accomplish something)
# 12    ταχυδρομείο                                         the post office, postal service
# 13       τηλεφωνώ                     to phone, to telephone (the act of calling someone)
# 14       υπογραφή                                          the signature, (fig) agreement
```

This is the data in the `Word` column arranged correctly:

```
sort(wds$Word)

#  [1] "γλώσσα"         "γραμματόσημο"   "διαδίκτυο"      "δίκτυο"         "έξοδος"        
#  [6] "επικοινωνώ"     "θέση"           "μήνυμα"         "μυστικό"        "πραγματικότητα"
# [11] "προσπάθεια"     "ταχυδρομείο"    "τηλεφωνώ"       "υπογραφή"
```

I think the issue is strictly tied to the accent mark. I find it really odd that `sort()` does it correctly while `dplyr::arrange` does not. Is there something I should be doing differently with `dplyr::arrange()`?

Comment: `sort()` is using the system's locale while `dplyr::arrange()` does not. There's a `dplyr.legacy_locale` option which can be set to `TRUE`, but the recommended method is to specify the locale in the function call: `wds %>% arrange(Word, .locale = "el")`. [Reference table for locales](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is the locale used to order character vectors. Since `dplyr 1.1.0` `arrange` by default

> uses the "C" locale unless the dplyr.legacy_locale global option escape hatch is active. (`?arrange`)

which

> has the benefit of being completely reproducible across all supported R versions and operating systems. (`?`dplyr-locale``)

But you can get the same result as with `sort` or `order` by switching to the legacy behavior (or setting the locale explicitly via the `.locale`argument) which will use the system locale.

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

withr::with_options(
  list(dplyr.legacy_locale = TRUE), wds %>% arrange(Word)
)
#>              Word
#> 1          γλώσσα
#> 2    γραμματόσημο
#> 3       διαδίκτυο
#> 4          δίκτυο
#> 5          έξοδος
#> 6      επικοινωνώ
#> 7            θέση
#> 8          μήνυμα
#> 9         μυστικό
#> 10 πραγματικότητα
#> 11     προσπάθεια
#> 12    ταχυδρομείο
#> 13       τηλεφωνώ
#> 14       υπογραφή
#>                                                                     trans2
#> 1  the (anatomy, shoe, figuratively) tongue, language, (fish species) sole
#> 2                                                        the postage stamp
#> 3                                                             the internet
#> 4                                                     the computer network
#> 5                           the exit, outing, the act of going out, exodus
#> 6                                  to talk, interact, contact, communicate
#> 7                           the seat, position, job, post, station, status
#> 8                               the (lit or fig) message, email, text, SMS
#> 9                                                      the secret, mystery
#> 10                                                  the reality, actuality
#> 11            the attempt (to do something), try (to accomplish something)
#> 12                                         the post office, postal service
#> 13                     to phone, to telephone (the act of calling someone)
#> 14                                          the signature, (fig) agreement
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you may need to specify `.locale`

```
> wds %>%
+   arrange(Word, .locale = "en")
             Word
1          γλώσσα
2    γραμματόσημο
3       διαδίκτυο
4          δίκτυο
5          έξοδος
6      επικοινωνώ
7            θέση
8          μήνυμα
9         μυστικό
10 πραγματικότητα
11     προσπάθεια
12    ταχυδρομείο
13       τηλεφωνώ
14       υπογραφή
                                                                    trans2
1  the (anatomy, shoe, figuratively) tongue, language, (fish species) sole
2                                                        the postage stamp
3                                                             the internet
4                                                     the computer network
5                           the exit, outing, the act of going out, exodus
6                                  to talk, interact, contact, communicate
7                           the seat, position, job, post, station, status
8                               the (lit or fig) message, email, text, SMS
9                                                      the secret, mystery
10                                                  the reality, actuality
11            the attempt (to do something), try (to accomplish something)
12                                         the post office, postal service
13                     to phone, to telephone (the act of calling someone)
14                                          the signature, (fig) agreement
```